# How to compile C GTK3+ program in Ubuntu for windows?

Tags: gtk, c, gtk3, cross-compilation, mingw32

I am using and gcc-7 and mingw-w64.I want to compile a c gtk3+ program in Linux using mingw so that it will produce .exe file which can be run in windows.I am able to Compile normal c programs using mingw,But I can't compile gtk programs.I can compile gtk programs with gcc but not with mingw.

I had installed mingw as told here :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786014/how-to-compile-executable-for-windows-with-gcc-with-linux-subsystem

Now I want to compile window program which I got from https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html#id-1.2.3.5

```
 smit@smit-Aspire-5742:~/programs/c programs/test$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc test.c `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0 --libs`
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/libgtk-3.dll.a when searching for -lgtk-3
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/libgtk-3.dll.a when searching for -lgtk-3
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgtk-3
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/li /libgdk-3.dll.a when searching for -lgdk-3
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/libgdk-3.dll.a when searching for -lgdk-3
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgdk-3
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.dll.a when searching for -lpangocairo-1.0
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/pangocairo-1.0.lib when searching for -lpangocairo-1.0
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.dll.a when searching for -lpangocairo-1.0
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/pangocairo-1.0.lib when searching for -lpangocairo-1.0
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/pangocairo-1.0.lib when searching for -lpangocairo-1.0
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lpangocairo-1.0
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.dll.a when searching for -lpangoft2-1.0
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/pangoft2-1.0.lib when searching for -lpangoft2-1.0
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.dll.a when searching for -lpangoft2-1.0
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/pangoft2-1.0.lib when searching for -lpangoft2-1.0
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/pangoft2-1.0.lib when searching for -lpangoft2-1.0
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lpangoft2-1.0
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/libfreetype.dll.a when searching for -lfreetype
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/libfreetype.dll.a when searching for -lfreetype
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lfreetype
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/libfontconfig.dll.a when searching for -lfontconfig
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/fontconfig.lib when searching for -lfontconfig
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/libfontconfig.dll.a when searching for -lfontconfig
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/fontconfig.lib when searching for -lfontconfig
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/fontconfig.lib when searching for -lfontconfig
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lfontconfig
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/libpangowin32-1.0.dll.a when searching for -lpangowin32-1.0
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/pangowin32-1.0.lib when searching for -lpangowin32-1.0
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/libpangowin32-1.0.dll.a when searching for -lpangowin32-1.0
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/pangowin32-1.0.lib when searching for -lpangowin32-1.0
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/pangowin32-1.0.lib when searching for -lpangowin32-1.0
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lpangowin32-1.0
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/libpango-1.0.dll.a when searching for -lpango-1.0
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/pango-1.0.lib when searching for -lpango-1.0
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/libpango-1.0.dll.a when searching for -lpango-1.0
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/pango-1.0.lib when searching for -lpango-1.0
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/pango-1.0.lib when searching for -lpango-1.0
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lpango-1.0
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/libatk-1.0.dll.a when searching for -latk-1.0
 /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/atk-1.0.lib when searching for -latk-1.0
  /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/libatk-1.0.dll.a when searching for -latk-1.0
  /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/atk-1.0.lib when searching for -latk-1.0
  /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/atk-1.0.lib when searching for -latk-1.0
  /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -latk-1.0
  /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/libcairo-gobject.dll.a when searching for -lcairo-gobject
  /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/libcairo-gobject.dll.a when searching for -lcairo-gobject
  /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lcairo-gobject
  /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/libcairo.dll.a when searching for -lcairo
  /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/cairo.lib when searching for -lcairo
  /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib/libcairo.dll.a when searching for -lcairo
  /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: skipping incompatible /opt/gtk3-dos/lib
```

and so .......( I am pasting the last line as this output is way more big)

```
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I already went via this tutorial :-http://www.tarnyko.net/en/?q=node/45

Now vis [this](http://www.tarnyko.net/en/?q=node/45) tutorail again but this time I had downloaded `gtk+-bundle_3.6.4-20131201_win64.zip` and now I am getting this output:-

```
 smit@smit-Aspire-5742:~/programs/c programs/test$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc test.c `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0 --libs`
 In file included from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include/glibconfig.h:9:0,
             from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:32,
             from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h:32,
             from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:30,
             from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkconfig.h:13,
             from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdk.h:30,
             from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:30,
             from test.c:1:
  /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h: In function ‘_GLIB_CHECKED_ADD_U64’:
  /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:232:53: error: size of array ‘_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_0’ is negative
   #define G_STATIC_ASSERT(expr) typedef char G_PASTE (_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_, __COUNTER__)[(expr) ? 1 : -1] G_GNUC_UNUSED
                                                 ^
   /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:229:47: note: in definition of macro ‘G_PASTE_ARGS’
   #define G_PASTE_ARGS(identifier1,identifier2) identifier1 ## identifier2
                                           ^
    /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:232:44: note: in expansion of macro ‘G_PASTE’
    #define G_STATIC_ASSERT(expr) typedef char G_PASTE (_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_, __COUNTER__)[(expr) ? 1 : -1] G_GNUC_UNUSED
                                        ^
    /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:422:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘G_STATIC_ASSERT’
    G_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof (unsigned long long) == sizeof (guint64));
       ^
    In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gio.h:46:0,
             from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkapplaunchcontext.h:28,
             from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdk.h:32,
             from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:30,
             from test.c:1:
    /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gcredentials.h: At top level:
    /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gcredentials.h:75:1: error: unknown type name ‘uid_t’
    uid_t            g_credentials_get_unix_user      (GCredentials    *credentials,
     ^
    /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gcredentials.h:79:52: error: unknown type name ‘uid_t’
                                                uid_t           uid,
                                                ^
```

Comment: In the first case, where did the files in `/opt/gtk3-dos/lib/` come from? In the second case, are you sure you set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` appropriately (so that it finds the files for the target platform, rather than those of your host system)?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but the problem is that `/usr/include/gtk*` headers are platform dependent. I.e. to build gtk with mingw you'd need to use libs and includes from the `/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/` *(or wherever it is)*. [See also this for details](https://github.com/grindhold/libgtkflow/issues/20).

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70726902/518879

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I attempted to follow [this](http://www.tarnyko.net/en/?q=node/45) tutorial 5 or maybe more times and I found what was wrong. I was extracting commands from the wrong directories and downloading the wrong version of *GTK+ 3 Windows binaries*.

My version of mingw is mingw64 thus I needed to download `win64` version.

and I was executing command `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/gtk3-win64/lib/pkgconfig` from /opt/gtk3-win64,but I needed to execute this command from the directory in which my test.c file was located.

I'll make this tutorial easy for future readers.

1. Install `mingw cross-compiler` by the command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install mingw-w64
   ```
2. Download *GTK+ 3 Windows binaries* from here (the link in [this tutorial](http://www.tarnyko.net/en/?q=node/45) is old, here is latest link: http://win32builder.gnome.org/).
   Download the appropriate version as I was downloading the wrong version. Don't make the same mistake as I did.
3. Extract the zip file in `/opt/gtkwin` (recommended) by command

   ```
   sudo mkdir /opt/gtkwin && sudo unzip <name of the zip file> -d /opt/gtkwin
   ```
4. Use the directory in which you have extracted the zip file. In this case I have extracted in `/opt/gtkwin/` and executed the following command:

   ```
   find /opt/gtkwin -name '*.pc' -exec sudo sed -e 's@^prefix=.*@prefix=/opt/gtkwin@' -i
   ```
5. Go to the directory in which you have the `.c` file which you which to compile and execute this command:

   ```
   export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/gtkwin/lib/pkgconfig
   ```
6. Compile the program by:

   - for 64-bit:

     ```
     x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc test.c $(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0 --libs)
     ```
   - for 32-bit:

     ```
     i586-mingw32msvc-gcc test.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0)
     ```

Also you should visit [this tutorial](http://www.tarnyko.net/en/?q=node/45) as I had learn this from there.

This will create  an `.exe` file which can't run in UNIX as it is targeted to run on DOS.

Comment: I know that I am not supposed to use comments for "+1"ing, but I have spent a great deal of time looking for this information and really appreciate your research. I wish that it supported a version of gtk+ newer than 2013, but that is fine by me at this point.

Comment: @Greenbeard It really feels nice that it helped you. I'll sleep with more peace today

Comment: Note: win32builder.gnome.org is also outdated now ;(

Comment: I think this site contains the binaries from the broken link (or similar ones): http://www.tarnyko.net/dl/

Comment: @steve GTK+ 3.6.4 is like years and years old. I suppose we now should use MSYS2: https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows/#using-gtk-from-msys2-packages

Comment: Well.. actually to correct myself. Msys2 is for Windows machines. So we are talking about cross compiling. Maybe I and you should consider MXE: https://github.com/mxe/mxe

Comment: See also my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70726902/518879

Comment: here you can download my pre-build binaries (MXE project): https://gitlab.melroy.org/melroy/gtk-3-bundle-for-windows

Answer (score 1):

MXE gives ok results. The compiled executable takes a while to load up, and also brings up an empty command prompt. However, this is the only thing I tried that remotely worked.

### Summary:

- Install MXE per [the official tutorial](https://mxe.cc/#tutorial)
- ```
  x86_64-w64-mingw32.static-gcc -o OUTFILE.exe INFILE.c `x86_64-w64-mingw32.static-pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
  ```
- `OUTFILE.exe` should now be ready to run on a computer with Windows. Copy it over and double click it, or launch it from the command prompt.

### Details

(Mostly summarized from their tutorial)

```
apt-get install autoconf automake autopoint bash bison bzip2 flex g++ g++-multilib gettext git gperf intltool libc6-dev-i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libltdl-dev libssl-dev libtool-bin libxml-parser-perl lzip make openssl p7zip-full patch perl python ruby sed unzip wget xz-utils

git clone https://github.com/mxe/mxe.git
sudo mv mxe /opt/mxe
cd /opt/mxe
make MXE_TARGETS='x86_64-w64-mingw32.static' cc gtk3
```

That should create the cross compiler, linker, and appropriate libraries in `/opt/mxe/usr/bin`. They'll all be named something crazy like `x86_64-w64-mingw32.static-pkg-config`. That's a lot to type! Use makefiles or something so you don't have to type it all out every time.

Add the following line to `~/.bashrc` (or whatever script your shell runs automatically):

```
export PATH=/opt/mxe/usr/bin:${PATH}
```

Close and reopen your terminal. `echo $PATH` should include `/opt/mxe/usr/bin`. You can now compile things with the command `x86_64-w64-mingw32.static-gcc` (used just like normal `gcc`). Make sure to use `x86_64-w64-mingw32.static-pkg-config` in place of regular `pkg-config`.

### Notes:

Maybe MXE-compiled executeables are slow for me it is secretly embedding debug stuff. Maybe mingw can take flags exclude that? Maybe also there are flags to not open the blank command prompt?

Some of the `apt-get` package installs may be unnecessary, idk.

You should do `make MXE_TARGETS='x86_64-w64-mingw32.static' cc gtk3` instead of just `make` because `make` generates every single package. That takes very long and will fail on random packages. Some of them can be excluded with the -o flag; for example, `make -o cloog -o gdal -o graphicsmagick` will exclude the `cloog`, `gdal`, and `graphicsmagick` packages, but that doesn't work on some packages. You should only make the specific packages you need.

`MXE_TARGETS='x86_64-w64-mingw32.static'` makes the 64 bit version (32 bit is default). Besides the `gtk` package, we need `cc` for `gcc` and `pkg-config`. Also note that it is `gtk3`, instead of just `gtk` like it says in their documentation.

Short guide to `pkg-config` for complete n00bs: To use `#includes` in libraries besides the C standard library and your own work, you need `pkg-config` to tell the C compiler where they are. Basically, the command `pkg-config --cflags --libs LIBRARY_NAME`, will look through a set of default directories for `LIBRARY_NAME.pc` files, which contain instructions to make the flags, which can then be passed as arguments to `gcc`.

The `LIBRARY_NAME` for `gtk3` is `gtk+-3.0`, for some reason. If you can't figure out what the `LIBRARY_NAME` for a lib is, you can usually use the `find` command with a wildcard. For example, `find /opt/mxe/usr -Iname gtk*.pc`. The `I` in `-Iname` means case insensitive.

Comment: See also my reply here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70726902/518879